# Android: displaying multiple images with XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I have a picture that is divided into 9 sections, which I need to display as one reconstructed image. I used this XML to display the first 6 sections, and the first row looks fine with the 3 images contiguous and filling the horizontal space, but the second row has smaller images separated by gaps.  I do not understand why the second row looks so much different than the first even with the same XML instructions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TableRow>       
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington0" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington1" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington2" >
        </ImageView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington3" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington4" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/picTile"
            android:src="@drawable/washington5" >
        </ImageView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not great at layouts myself, but a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) might be easier than manually creating a table. You should also look into ImageView's [`scaleType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) attribute, it might help.

Comment: Sorry to contradict @Sam, but IMO @Doug is definitely on the right track. This is a job for `TableView` in the direction he is already going, not `GridView`.

Comment: I agree with @DavidManpearl - GridView is geared towards dynamic imageviews tied to adapters. However, @Sam's suggestion about the `scaleType` attribute is valid. It might play a role here.

Comment: Giving equal layout_weight to each TableRow and then adding android:scaleType="fitXY" to each ImageView created a smooth picture, although it was stretched a bit vertically to fill the space. Using android:scaleType="centerInside" kept the picture parts in the right proportions, but left gaps in between the rows. So if I can eliminate those gaps it would be perfect.